# BEM: Naming conventions

Tags: css, bem

I would like some clarification about BEM convention.  Say that I have a card block which will be used in two places/pages `registration` and `dashboard`.

HTML structure for card looks something like this:

```
<div class="card">
  <header class="cardheader">
    <h3 class="cardheader_title">
      Some Title
    </h3>
  </header>

  <section class="card-body">
    <!-- this can contain other blocks.  -->
    <!-- for example a nav and a form. or simple an acticle  -->
  </section>
</div>
```

I would like to write `scss` for this once and then be able to use it wherever I need it. So let's take the registration page for example.

```
<div class="card registration-card">
  <header class="cardheader registration-cardheader">
    <h3 class="cardheader_title registration-cardheader__title">
      Some Title
    </h3>
  </header>

  <section class="card-body registration-cardbody">
    <!-- this can contain other blocks.  -->
    <!-- for example a nav and a form. or simple an acticle  -->
  </section>
</div>
```

And then repeat the same for dashboard:

```
<div class="card dashboard-card">
  <header class="cardheader dashboard-cardheader">
    <h3 class="cardheader_title dashboard-cardheader__title">
      Some Title
    </h3>
  </header>

  <section class="card-body dashboard-cardbody">
    <!-- this can contain other blocks.  -->
    <!-- for example a nav and a form. or simple an acticle  -->
  </section>
</div>
```

*I am only working with `block` and `block__modifer` in the above examples*

Is the above an `acceptable` BEM approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely acceptable and is called **mixes** in BEM methodology. See https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#mix for details (please also be aware that in official docs different separators are used so don't be confused).